# While clicking on editext box which is there in dialogbox. the implicit keyboard have to hide

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialog, android-keypad

I have a edittextbox on the dialog box. while i click on the editext box the keyboard must be disabled.

Here i have the following code where the edit tetxtbox is pressent.

public class NumberPicker extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener,
        OnFocusChangeListener, OnLongClickListener {

```
private static final String TAG = "NumberPicker";
private static final int DEFAULT_MAX = 10;
private static final int DEFAULT_MIN = 1;
public static String quantityForOrder;

public interface OnChangedListener {
    void onChanged(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal);
}

public interface Formatter {
    String toString(int value);
}

/*
 * Use a custom NumberPicker formatting callback to use two-digit
 * minutes strings like "01".  Keeping a static formatter etc. is the
 * most efficient way to do this; it avoids creating temporary objects
 * on every call to format().
 */
public static final NumberPicker.Formatter TWO_DIGIT_FORMATTER =
        new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
            final StringBuilder mBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            final java.util.Formatter mFmt = new java.util.Formatter(mBuilder);
            final Object[] mArgs = new Object[1];
            public String toString(int value) {
                mArgs[0] = value;
                mBuilder.delete(0, mBuilder.length());
                mFmt.format("%02d", mArgs);
                return mFmt.toString();
            }
    };

private final Handler mHandler;
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (mIncrement) {
            changeCurrent(mCurrent + 1);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, mSpeed);
        } else if (mDecrement) {
            changeCurrent(mCurrent - 1);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, mSpeed);
        }
    }
};

private final EditText mText;
private final InputFilter mNumberInputFilter;

private String[] mDisplayedValues;
protected int mStart;
protected int mEnd;
protected int mCurrent;
protected int mPrevious;
private OnChangedListener mListener;
private Formatter mFormatter;
private long mSpeed = 300;

private boolean mIncrement;
private boolean mDecrement;

public NumberPicker(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public NumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

@SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
public NumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_picker, this, true);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    InputFilter inputFilter = new NumberPickerInputFilter();
    mNumberInputFilter = new NumberRangeKeyListener();
    mIncrementButton = (NumberPickerButton) findViewById(R.id.increment);
    mIncrementButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mIncrementButton.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    mIncrementButton.setNumberPicker(this);
    mDecrementButton = (NumberPickerButton) findViewById(R.id.decrement);
    mDecrementButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mDecrementButton.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    mDecrementButton.setNumberPicker(this);

    mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timepicker_input);
    mText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    mText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {inputFilter});
    mText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);


    if (!isEnabled()) {
        setEnabled(false);
    }

    mStart = DEFAULT_MIN;
    mEnd = DEFAULT_MAX;
```

//        mText.setText(mStart);
    }

```
@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
    mIncrementButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    mDecrementButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    mText.setEnabled(enabled);
}

public void setOnChangeListener(OnChangedListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public void setFormatter(Formatter formatter) {
    mFormatter = formatter;
}

/**
 * Set the range of numbers allowed for the number picker. The current
 * value will be automatically set to the start.
 *
 * @param start the start of the range (inclusive)
 * @param end the end of the range (inclusive)
 */
public void setRange(int start, int end) {
    mStart = start;
    mEnd = end;
    mCurrent = start;
    updateView();
}

/**
 * Set the range of numbers allowed for the number picker. The current
 * value will be automatically set to the start. Also provide a mapping
 * for values used to display to the user.
 *
 * @param start the start of the range (inclusive)
 * @param end the end of the range (inclusive)
 * @param displayedValues the values displayed to the user.
 */
public void setRange(int start, int end, String[] displayedValues) {
    mDisplayedValues = displayedValues;
    mStart = start;
    mEnd = end;
    mCurrent = start;
    updateView();
}

public void setCurrent(int current) {
    mCurrent = current;
    updateView();
}

/**
 * The speed (in milliseconds) at which the numbers will scroll
 * when the the +/- buttons are longpressed. Default is 300ms.
 */
public void setSpeed(long speed) {
    mSpeed = speed;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    validateInput(mText);
    if (!mText.hasFocus()) mText.requestFocus();

    // now perform the increment/decrement
    if (R.id.increment == v.getId()) {
        changeCurrent(mCurrent + 1);
    } else if (R.id.decrement == v.getId()) {
        changeCurrent(mCurrent - 1);
    }
}

private String formatNumber(int value) {
    return (mFormatter != null)
            ? mFormatter.toString(value)
            : String.valueOf(value);
}

protected void changeCurrent(int current) {

    // Wrap around the values if we go past the start or end
    if (current > mEnd) {
        current = mStart;
    } else if (current < mStart) {
        current = mEnd;
    }
    mPrevious = mCurrent;
    mCurrent = current;

    notifyChange();
    updateView();
}

protected void notifyChange() {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onChanged(this, mPrevious, mCurrent);
    }
}

protected void updateView() {

    /* If we don't have displayed values then use the
     * current number else find the correct value in the
     * displayed values for the current number.
     */
    if (mDisplayedValues == null) {
        mText.setText(formatNumber(mCurrent));
    } else {
        mText.setText(mDisplayedValues[mCurrent - mStart]);
    }
    mText.setSelection(mText.getText().length());
    System.out.println("my value in number picker"+mText.getText().length());
    System.out.println("my value in number picker"+mText.getText().toString());
    quantityForOrder = mText.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("my value with static : "+quantityForOrder);
}

private void validateCurrentView(CharSequence str) {
    int val = getSelectedPos(str.toString());
    if ((val >= mStart) && (val <= mEnd)) {
        if (mCurrent != val) {
            mPrevious = mCurrent;
            mCurrent = val;
            notifyChange();
        }
    }
    updateView();
}

public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

    /* When focus is lost check that the text field
     * has valid values.
     */
    if (!hasFocus) {
        validateInput(v);
    }
}

private void validateInput(View v) {
    String str = String.valueOf(((TextView) v).getText());
    if ("".equals(str)) {

        // Restore to the old value as we don't allow empty values
        updateView();
    } else {

        // Check the new value and ensure it's in range
        validateCurrentView(str);
    }
}

/**
 * We start the long click here but rely on the {@link NumberPickerButton}
 * to inform us when the long click has ended.
 */
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

    /* The text view may still have focus so clear it's focus which will
     * trigger the on focus changed and any typed values to be pulled.
     */
    mText.clearFocus();

    if (R.id.increment == v.getId()) {
        mIncrement = true;
        mHandler.post(mRunnable);
    } else if (R.id.decrement == v.getId()) {
        mDecrement = true;
        mHandler.post(mRunnable);
    }
    return true;
}

public void cancelIncrement() {
    mIncrement = false;
}

public void cancelDecrement() {
    mDecrement = false;
}

private static final char[] DIGIT_CHARACTERS = new char[] {
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
};

private NumberPickerButton mIncrementButton;
private NumberPickerButton mDecrementButton;

private class NumberPickerInputFilter implements InputFilter {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (mDisplayedValues == null) {
            return mNumberInputFilter.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);
        }
        CharSequence filtered = String.valueOf(source.subSequence(start, end));
        String result = String.valueOf(dest.subSequence(0, dstart))
                + filtered
                + dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length());
        String str = String.valueOf(result).toLowerCase();
        for (String val : mDisplayedValues) {
            val = val.toLowerCase();
            if (val.startsWith(str)) {
                return filtered;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}

private class NumberRangeKeyListener extends NumberKeyListener {

    // XXX This doesn't allow for range limits when controlled by a
    // soft input method!
    public int getInputType() {
        return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
    }

    @Override
    protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
        return DIGIT_CHARACTERS;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        CharSequence filtered = super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);
        if (filtered == null) {
            filtered = source.subSequence(start, end);
        }

        String result = String.valueOf(dest.subSequence(0, dstart))
                + filtered
                + dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length());

        if ("".equals(result)) {
            return result;
        }
        int val = getSelectedPos(result);

        /* Ensure the user can't type in a value greater
         * than the max allowed. We have to allow less than min
         * as the user might want to delete some numbers
         * and then type a new number.
         */
        if (val > mEnd) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return filtered;
        }
    }
}

private int getSelectedPos(String str) {
    if (mDisplayedValues == null) {
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < mDisplayedValues.length; i++) {

            /* Don't force the user to type in jan when ja will do */
            str = str.toLowerCase();
            if (mDisplayedValues[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(str)) {
                return mStart + i;
            }
        }

        /* The user might have typed in a number into the month field i.e.
         * 10 instead of OCT so support that too.
         */
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(str);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            /* Ignore as if it's not a number we don't care */
        }
    }
    return mStart;
}

/**
 * @return the current value.
 */
public int getCurrent() {
    return mCurrent;
}
```

}

if i am editing the editetxt box via keyboard then i am getting the following bug.

10-08 16:16:01.194: WARN/System.err(27016): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer
10-08 16:16:01.202: WARN/System.err(27016):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:406)
10-08 16:16:01.202: WARN/System.err(27016):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
10-08 16:16:01.202: WARN/System.err(27016):     at com.cpt.coffee.activity.CoffeeOrder$EfficientAdapter$1$1.onClick(CoffeeOrder.java:316)
10-08 16:16:01.202: WARN/System.err(27016):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
10-08 16:16:01.202: WARN/System.err(27016):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
10-08 16:16:01.202: WARN/System.err(27016):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-08 16:16:01.202: WARN/System.err(27016):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-08 16:16:01.202: WARN/System.err(27016):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-08 16:16:01.202: WARN/System.err(27016):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-08 16:16:01.212: WARN/System.err(27016):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 16:16:01.212: WARN/System.err(27016):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-08 16:16:01.212: WARN/System.err(27016):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-08 16:16:01.212: WARN/System.err(27016):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-08 16:16:01.212: WARN/System.err(27016):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the keyboard using

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Also you can try setting it in listener,so it is not called in dialog itself:

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
@Override
 public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
     InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
     imm.showSoftInput(textEdit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
InputMethodManager im=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: This iam unable to do because the entire dialogbox is an widget called numberpicker widget. the whole class is extended from the LinearLayout. so i cant able to get : getSystemService

Comment: ok then pass the activity of the class where the dialog is called and accept it through constructor in the class where you extend LinearLayout

and change the above code as


activity.im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);